# For groups $G$ and $H$, $a \in G$ and $b \in H$, where $|a| = j$ and $|b| = k; (a,b) \in (G\times H)$ has order ${\rm lcm}(j,k)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How do I show for $a \in G$ and $b \in H$, where $|a| = j$ and $|b| = k; (a,b) \in (G\times H)$ has order ${\rm lcm}(j,k)$?

Here is what I have so far:

Let $|a| = j$ and $|b| = k$. Let $s = {\rm lcm}(j,k)$. Then $s = jx = ky$ for $x,y \in\Bbb Z.$  Then $(a,b)^s = (a^s, b^s) = ((a^j)^x, (b^k)^y) = (e_G^x, e_H^y) = (e_G, e_H).$   Thus the order of $(a,b)$ divides $s$, e.g $|(a,b)||s$.

But I know this is not enough yet, since I have to show the order of $(a,b) = s$.

Comment: See [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Order_of_Group_Element_in_Group_Direct_Product).

Comment: I suspect this question has been asked & answered here multiple times. Please do a search for it.

Comment: Done a search, john?